# Is conditional hierarchical linear mixed effect model the same as mixed effect model

Tags: mixed-models

I have been asked to do a conditional hierarchical linear mixed effect model on my dataset (n=6 per condition, 4 conditions) as the datapoints were taken from the same subject (cell isolate). I was wondering whether its the same as the mixed effect analysis (as is found in Graphpad PRISM).
Sorry for the stupid question- by far not a statistician.
Many thanks!